# X conifguration Throws Error - 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xorg, mythtv, xorg.conf

I have a brand new 18.04.3 desktop. The only application I've installed is MythTV.

When I run X -configure I get:

```
(++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
```

X starts but Mythfrontend is non-responsive when run. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try supported release of Ubuntu, 10.04 is long dead

Comment: Sorry typo. 18.04.3

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled xorg and gdm3. I still have the error but mythfrontend is running now. Still don't know what the error is.